# Error "ReferenceError: pathsToModuleNameMapper is not defined" when trying to run jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, webpack, jestjs

I'm trying to run jest in a javascript react.js project that is using webpack, babel, enzyme and jasmine (among other things) and I'm seeing the error:

> ReferenceError: pathsToModuleNameMapper is not defined

Here's the console.output:

```
macbook-pro:$ ./node_modules/.bin/jest --coverage
ReferenceError: pathsToModuleNameMapper is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/github-image/hipocampo/jest.config.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at readConfigFileAndSetRootDir (/Volumes/github-image/hipocampo/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-config/build/readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js:119:22)
    at readConfig (/Volumes/github-image/hipocampo/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:217:65)
    at readConfigs (/Volumes/github-image/hipocampo/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:406:32)
```

Here's the jest configuration in package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "spec"
    ]
  }
```

And here are some of the package versions:

```
"jest": "26.6.1"
"babel-jest": "26.6.1"
"jasmine": "3.5.0"
"jasmine-enzyme": "7.1.2"
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "5.0.2"
"enzyme": "3.11.0"
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.15.2"
"webpack": "4.42.0"
```

Comment: The error clearly says there's a problem in hipocampo/jest.config.js

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that earlier I had copied into the project jest.config.js and I had forgotten about it. It contained the lines:

```
const { pathsToModuleNameMapper } = require('ts-jest/utils');
```

and

```
moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths || {}, {
    prefix: 'spec/'
```

I removed the reference to pathsToModuleNameMapper and updated moduleNameMapper to

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "spec/mocks/*.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "spec/mocks/*.js"
```

and the error message went away.